# How can you check if a list of strings match all the words in your phrase?

Tags: c#, string, search-engine

I have a list of strings

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "hello world", "how are you", "what is going on" };
```

and I need to check if the string I give uses every word in one of the strings in `arr`

so let's say I have

```
string s = "hello are going on";
```

it would be a match because all of the words in `s` are in one of the strings in `arr`

```
string s = "hello world man"
```

this one would not be a match because "man" is not in any of the strings in `arr`

I know how to write a "longer" method to do this but is there a nice linq query that I can write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "hello world", "how are you", "what is going on" };
string s = "hello are going on";
string s2 = "hello world man";
bool bs = s.Split(' ').All(word => arr.Any(sentence => sentence.Contains(word)));
bool bs2 = s2.Split(' ').All(word => arr.Any(sentence => sentence.Contains(word)));
```

Comment: +1: Elegant, simple, nice. No needs to SelectMany as Nathan and I did ! You could event one line it using a function or an Func delegate as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
        string[] arr = new string[] { "hello world", "how are you", "what is going on" };

        HashSet<string> incuded = new HashSet<string>(arr.SelectMany(ss => ss.Split(' ')));

        string s = "hello are going on";
        string s2 = "hello world man";

        bool valid1 = s.Split(' ').All(ss => incuded.Contains(ss));
        bool valid2 = s2.Split(' ').All(ss => incuded.Contains(ss));
```

Enjoy! (I used the hash set for performace, you could replace "incuded" (silly typo) with arr.SelectMany(ss => ss.Split(' ')).Unique() in all cases.

Comment: Unnecessary memory overhead in my opinion.

Comment: Really depends on the size of the list. For this small amount you are completely right, if the number of strings gets up into the thousands or so than you are going to want to look into hashing for the search.

Answer (score 0):

I try my best to one-line it :)

```
var arr = new [] { "hello world", "how are you", "what is going on" };

var check = new Func<string, string[], bool>((ss, ar) => 
    ss.Split(' ').All(y => ar.SelectMany(x => 
        x.Split(' ')).Contains(y)));

var isValid1 = check("hello are going on", arr);
var isValid2 = check("hello world man", arr);
```